# $\int\text{e}^{-ax^2 } \text{erf}\left(bx + c\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, error-function

I'm hoping to find a closed expression for the following integral.
$$
\int\text{e}^{-ax^2 } \text{erf}\left(bx + c\right) dx
$$
[One can find](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf) a solution for a family of products between exponentials and error functions. None of which apparently have the offset term in the error function.

I have tried tackling the problem with two approaches.

**Approach #1:** Expanding the error function hoping to find nice cancelations leading to the maclerin series of some known elementary function. Following a similar approach by [Alex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78615/integrating-a-product-of-exponentials-and-error-functions?rq=1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\text{e}^{-ax^2 } \text{erf}\left(bx + c\right) dx &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n!(2n+1)} \int(bx+c)^{2n +1} \text{e}^{-ax^2} dx \\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n!(2n+1)}  \int 
 \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} {{2n+1}\choose{k}} (bx)^{k} c^{2n+1-k} \text{e}^{-ax^2} dx \\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n!(2n+1)}   
 \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} {{2n+1}\choose{k}} c^{2n+1-k} b^k\int x^{k}  \text{e}^{-ax^2} dx 
= \\
&\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n!(2n+1)}   
 \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} {{2n+1}\choose{k}} c^{2n+1-k} b^k \left(-\frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{k+1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2},ax^2\right)\right) 
\\  
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{\pi}}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n!(2n+1)}   
 \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} {{2n+1}\choose{k}} c^{2n+1-k} \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^k  \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2},ax^2\right) 
\end{aligned}
$$

I have used the binomial expansion for $(bx + c)^{2n+1}$ and that $\int x^k \text{e}^{-ax^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2}a^{-\frac{k+1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2} ,ax^2\right)$ where $\Gamma(,)$ is the incomplete gamma function. Too bad, the last term can not be combined again in the form of a binomial expansion.

**Approach #2:** Instead of expanding the error function, I tried writing it in terms of the cumulative CDF function (Q-Function) as $\text{erf}(x) = 2\Phi(\sqrt{2} x) - 1$. However, the following can be shown to be true using integration under the integral sign with respect to $\mu$. [[Section 2.4](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~sidaw/home/_media/papers:icmldropout.pdf), and [ref]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682881/how-to-derive-integrals-with-error-function)

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(\lambda x) \text{e}^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}dx =\Phi\left(\frac{\lambda \mu}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2\sigma^2}}\right)
$$

Now with some change of variables and rescaling we are instead interested in the following integral:
$$
\int\text{e}^{a_1 x^2 + a_2 x} \text{erf}\left(x\right) dx = \underbrace{2\int \text{e}^{a_1 x^2 + a_2 x} \Phi(\sqrt{2} x) dx}_{I} - \underbrace{\int \text{e}^{a_1 x^2 + a_2 x} dx}_{easy}
$$

However, what I'm not certain of if I can use the trick of integration under integral sign for the indefinite integral labeled I. **Can I, with some change of variables, use the result deduced for the definite integral case as $\Phi\left(\frac{\lambda \mu}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2\sigma^2}}\right) + C(x)$?**

---

> **EDIT:** It seems that the problem in had has no closed form solution as pointed out by [user90369](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/332823/user90369). Also, [user90369](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/332823/user90369) has pointed out that the following more general case have no closed form solution.
>   $$
> \int x^{2n} \text{e}^{-ax^2} \text{erf}(bx+c) dx
> $$
>   I was wondering, if there are any good approximations that I can use here. By good, I mean refer to an error that is $|e(x)| \leq 10^{-5} \forall x$.
>   For starter, I was looking at the high accuracy approximations in [here](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm) for the erf function. Unfortunately, none of these approximations result into an integral that inherits a closed form solution. I, however, have the following suggested approach with the use of the following identity.
>   $$
> \text{erf}(bx+c) = 2 \Phi\left(\sqrt{2} (bx+c)\right) - 1
> $$
>   This results into the following:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \int\text{e}^{-ax^2 } \text{erf}\left(bx + c\right) dx = 2\int \text{e}^{-ax^2 } \Phi\left(\sqrt{2} (bx+c)\right) dx - \int \text{e}^{-ax^2 } dx
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   Now, one can use the approximation of the $\Phi$-function that results from applying Chernof's bound. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function)
>   $$
> \Phi(x) \approx \frac{1}{12} \text{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} + \frac{1}{4} \text{e}^{-\frac{2}{3} x^2}
> $$
>   I'd like to take a suggestion of how good is this approximation after computing the integral. Or maybe if there are other better approximations/recommendations that result into a manageable integral afterwards.

Comment: @user90369 Thanks. Would you care suggesting an approximation? For instance, all the approximations provided here http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm are not useful in solving the resulting integral. I was considering approximating the $\Phi$ function with an exponential from Chernof's bound.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function

Comment: @user90369 Also, there appears to be some hope for the definite integral case. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236490/closed-form-for-definite-integral-involving-erf-and-gaussian?rq=1

Comment: There is a *very* big difference between $\int$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ . Maybe someone can give you an useful answer if you decide where your focus is here.

Comment: @user90369 I'll edit my question to ask for a direction of some possible approximations. BTW, $\int \text{erf}(bx+c) dx = \left(\frac{c}{b}+x \right) \text{erf}(c+bx) + \frac{\text{e}^{-(c+bx)^2}}{b\sqrt{\pi}}$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+erf(a*x%2Bc)

Comment: If you use the method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236490/closed-form-for-definite-integral-involving-erf-and-gaussian?rq=1 (the link you've mentioned) you will get a formula for $ \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} \text{erf}(bx+c)dx$ . One must substitute $x$ by $(x-c)/b$ and then do the derivation of the integral with respect to $c$ .

Comment: @user90369 Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, that will not cut it for me. Since this expression will be later integrated over a different  parameter. Thus, a definite integral solution won't be of a great help in this case. Would you care having a look at the final edit to the OP regarding a suggestion/opinion of an approximation?

Comment: You haven't defined what a "good" approximation is here (for you) but anyway you can make numerical tests with some values and see whether they meet your expectations. To approximate $Q$ and therefore at the end $\,\text{erf} \,$ by sums of $e^{-a(x+b)^2}$ is of course a good idea.

Comment: I have written an answer which refers to Approach #1 . I hope this helps a bit. :-)

Comment: There is almost likely a closed form with [Wolfram’s Owen T function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwenT.html#:~:text=OwenT%5Bx%2Ca%5D%20is,a%20plane%20running%20from%20to%20.), but there is an accepted answer already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't know if this helps for an useful approximation but maybe it's better than nothing.* :-)

For $\,v\in\mathbb{N}_0\,$ we get

$$ \int x^{2v+1}e^{-ax^2}dx= -\frac{v!e^{-ax^2}}{2a^{v+1}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^v\frac{(ax^2)^j}{j!} + C_{2v+1} $$

and

$$ \int x^{2v}e^{-ax^2}dx= \frac{(2v)!\sqrt{a\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)}{2^v v!(2a)^{v+1}}-e^{-ax^2}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{v-1}\frac{(v-j)!(2v)!x^{2v-2j-1}}{2^j v!(2v-2j)!(2a)^{j+1}} + C_{2v} $$

and it follows:

\begin{align}
& \hphantom{ {}={}} \int e^{-ax^2} \text{erf}(bx+c)dx \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\int (bx+c)^{2k+1} e^{-ax^2} dx \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum_{v=0}^{2k+1}\binom {2k+1} v b^v c^{2k+1-v}\int x^v e^{-ax^2} dx \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum_{v=0}^k\binom {2k+1} {2v} b^{2v} c^{2k+1-2v}\int x^{2v} e^{-ax^2} dx \\ 
&\hspace{5mm} +\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum_{v=0}^k\binom {2k+1} {2v+1} b^{2v+1} c^{2k-2v}\int x^{2v+1} e^{-ax^2} dx \\ 
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)} 
\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \binom {2k+1} {2v} b^{2v}c^{2k-2v+1} \\
&\hspace{3cm}  \cdot \left( \frac{(2v)!\sqrt{a\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)}{2^v v!(2a)^{v+1}}-e^{-ax^2}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{v-1}\frac{(v-j)!(2v)!x^{2v-2j-1}}{2^j v!(2v-2j)!(2a)^{j+1}} \right) \\
&\hspace{5mm} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)} 
\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \binom {2k+1} {2v+1} b^{2v+1}c^{2k-2v} \frac{v!e^{-ax^2}}{2a^{v+1}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^v\frac{(ax^2)^j}{j!} + C \\
&= \sqrt{a\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \binom {2k+1} {2v} \frac{(2v)!b^{2v}c^{2k-2v+1}}{2^v v!(2a)^{v+1}} \\
&\hspace{5mm} -e^{-ax^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \binom {2k+1} {2v} b^{2v}c^{2k-2v+1}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{v-1}\frac{(v-j)!(2v)!x^{2v-2j-1}}{2^j v!(2v-2j)!(2a)^{j+1}} \\
&\hspace{5mm}  -e^{-ax^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(2k+1)}\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \binom {2k+1} {2v+1} b^{2v+1}c^{2k-2v} \frac{v!}{2a^{v+1}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^v\frac{(ax^2)^j}{j!} + C
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Not sure really if that helps alot. I was looking into some more simpler forms as the result of the required integral will be later integrated too over some other parameter. I have tried the approximation mentioned in the OP; however, this approximation is not continuous. Resulting in a disjunction in the final solution that is broken into pieces depending on the region of integration. This is because $\Phi(x) \approx \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} \forall x \ge 0$.

Comment: @AdelBibi : The series is the exact result. For simplification it's necessary to specify additional decision criteria, e.g. the value ranges ​​of the parameters.

Comment: I have looked at it more now. I think that should be a good approximation. However, may you detail the integral. Also, I don't quite see where did the error function disappear after the second line. Also, are there a missing equal signs from third and forth row? Could you add some details to it so that I can officially accept it as an answer?

Comment: @AdelBibi: Sorry, yes, you are right. I have add some steps. --- The error function doesn't disappear, it's a part of the solution. --- Missing equal signs ? No, but the terms and sums are partly too long for one line. (Maybe your screen display is different to mine ? Or do I misunderstand you ?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't imagine the expressions were that long and thought that there must be some missing equal signs somewhere especially I wasn't able to follow your initial solution. It is much more clearer now. To be honest, I still have to do some experiments to see how many factors do I need to consider from the sums to get an accurate approximation. That in general is very helpful to me and probably to some other future readers. Thanks!

Comment: @AdelBibi : You are welcome (and sorry for the inconvenience because of a too short explanation first). :-)