# What is the Fourier transform of the Skew normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, fourier-transform, gaussian-integral, error-function

I'm trying to see what is the Fourier transform of the [Skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution). My intuition and looking at [some formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682881/how-to-derive-integrals-with-error-function?rq=1) for integrals about the error function  suggests to me that it might be another Skew normal, just like the FT of a Gaussian is another Gaussian. I couldn't find any result on this question so I'm trying to derive it myself, but I want to know if this is a well know fact already.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page you linked, the Characteristic Function (CF) is right there in the table on the top right hand side of the page.  It indeed looks very much like a skew normal function.